Assignable-to function-like thing in c++
I'm writing code for a thing that uses Lisp-like data structures (i.e. cons cells) internally. So it makes sense for the two field members of the cons struct to be called x->car and x->cdr.
As you would probably expect, I assign to those fields. Sometimes it's chained, as in x->cdr->cdr->car (and yes, I do check to make sure the intermediary values are valid before doing this).
Because it's Lisp, however, I want to be able to use Lisp names for them, such as x->caddr, but that would obviously not work because it's chained pointers, not one single pointer.
Currently I am using a bunch of preprocessor macros like so:
#define car(x) ((x)->car)
#define cdr(x) ((x)->cdr)
#define caar(x) car(car(x))
#define cadr(x) car(cdr(x))
#define cdar(x) cdr(car(x))
#define cddr(x) cdr(cdr(x))
#define caaar(x) car(caar(x))
// and so on all the way up to caaaaaar / cddddddr

This allows me to write stuff like caddr(x) = y and have it work, because the macros expand into valid lvalues that can be assigned to.
However, the macros are not type checked. If I accidentally pass in a value that doesn't have car and cdr pointers, the error message is very hard to track down exactly what is the problem.
It also feels like a kludge too, as are most "preprocessor hacks".
I am looking for some way to express this that:

Does type checking
Is still a valid lvalue that can be assigned to
Does not use the preprocessor

Any pointers?
(No pun intended)

Just write a function that returns a reference. There's a lot of functions to write, but there are also a lot of macros.

Use inline functions returning references inline auto& car(X* x) { return x->car; }

Function templates are the way to get type safe "macros"

In general you should avoid macros in C++, just write functions (or function templates)

@NathanOliver Yes inline is still needed for function templates. I am afraid the OP still will get "weird" error messages if they use template <typename X> ....

I don't know LISP well enough (last time I even looked at it was more then 30 years ago) But this feels like a monadic approach to me : functions returning objects that have functions that can return objects.

@273K going to try your suggestion.

I'm reminded of Greenspun's Tenth Rule.

@cHao that was before we had parameter packs :)

I love macros:  car("Banana").  This makes more sense: struct Car_Dealer; Car_Dealer Joes_Hondas; car(Joes_Hondas);

answered by @273K's comment
inline object*& car(object* x) { return x->car; }
inline object*& cdr(object* x) { return x->cdr; }
inline object*& caar(object* x) { return car(car(x)); }
inline object*& cadr(object* x) { return car(cdr(x)); }
inline object*& cdar(object* x) { return cdr(car(x)); }
inline object*& cddr(object* x) { return cdr(cdr(x)); }
inline object*& caaar(object* x) { return car(caar(x)); }
// and so on

somehow, I forgot about C++ references

And you might double the overload count with const variant.

Can also be improved by adding assertion about nullptr pointer check.

@Jarod42 I considered that, but adding null checks on every car/cdr caused a significant performance penalty.

Then, function should take references, but indeed, it would be out of scope of the question ;-)
